# TeamCity command line build step can not find files

Tags: teamcity

So, when I attempt to run a script file in a TeamCity build step (Command line build step) I get the following error:

```
Step 1/8: Download provisioning profile (script file) (Command Line)
[12:23:07][Step 1/8] Starting: /Applications/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/83a21295522e711a/TeamCityCustomBuildScripts/DownloadProvisioningProfile.sh
[12:23:07][Step 1/8] in directory: /Applications/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/83a21295522e711a/Project
[12:23:07][Step 1/8] Cannot run process /Applications/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/83a21295522e711a/TeamCityCustomBuildScripts/DownloadProvisioningProfile.sh : file not found
[12:23:07][Step 1/8] Step Download provisioning profile (script file) (Command Line) failed with unexpected error
```

I can find and run the script manually at the exact place the build step tells me it can not find it.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like a file permission problem to me.

Comment: Might be. I was thinking that such an issue would give me an error message of the "permission denied" variety.

Comment: What is the command you used to run the script??

Comment: TeamCity allows one to browse to files that will be available after the given repositories have been retrieved. I just select the "DownloadProvisioningProfile.sh" file from there. (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Command+Line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was apparently line endings.

I had created the .sh file on windows with the `#!/bin/bash` shebang in the first line but the interpreter could not be found since the line was not terminated properly.

The solution was changing the line endings on my windows machine (using Notepad++ Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix LF)

Answer (score 1):

As commented, this appears to be a permission problem. Either on the file itself, or on one of the directories.

Which user does the teamcity agent run as?

Does that user have full access to the desired location?

Change the permissions so that the agent has access to the script and it should work.